# C - fprintf and printf inside loops don t print to screen

Tags: c, terminal, stdio

I just discovered that the function fprintf can be used to print something to the screen.

I have this minimal just below, however it doesn t output anything to the screen. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,j,k;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<0;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<3;k++)
            {
                printf("test\n");
                fprintf(stderr, "test\n");

            }
        }       
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am running ubuntu 14.04 and compiling this code as follows:
gcc main.c -o main

Answer (score 5):

Why should it print anything? One of your loops has an impossible condition:

```
    for(j=0;j<0;j++)
              ^---
```

since `j` starts at `0`, it can never be LESS than `0`, so the loop immediately exits without ever executing the body.

Answer (score 2):

Your second loop is wrong. `j` is initialized to zero and the conditional is `j<0`. With for loops the conditional is evaluated before the first iteration.

Comment: @J.Doe Yes I do. We've all made those sorts of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

> I have this minimal just below, however it doesn t output anything to the screen. Why?

It wouldn't because control never reaches to the `printf()` statement. Because your middle `for loop` has a test condition which always fails which prevents even inner `for loop` to execute.

```
for(j=0;j<0;j++)
.
.
```

The condition `j<0` when j is initialized with `0` will always evaluates to `false`. Fix the middle `for loop` and your problem will be solved.

You can debug your program using `gdb`. Learn few commands to work with `gdb` and you can see on your own where is the problem lies.